# I need to make a 3 row 4 column image gallery

Tags: html

I have this HTML and CSS, and I want to take these pictures and make them into a grid of 4 columns and 3 rows; but nothing I'm doing is changing anything. Also I need all of the images to be the same size.

Here is the HTML I already have:

```
</div>
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="CS1.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS2.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS3.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="CS4.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS5.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS6.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
  </div> 
  <div class="column">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="CS7.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS8.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS9.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="CS10.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS11.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    <img src="CS12.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I've been playing around with:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}


/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="CS1.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
      <img src="CS2.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
      <img src="CS3.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="CS4.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS5.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS6.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="CS7.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
          <img src="CS8.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
          <img src="CS9.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="CS10.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
            <img src="CS11.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
            <img src="CS12.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: also I need all of the images to be the same size i forgot to mention that

Comment: `/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */ ... flex: 50%`; if `flex: 50%` gives - or is expected to give - two columns, did you consider `flex: 25%` for four columns? Although I would suggest that CSS Grid would be better for this use-case.

Comment: At first, all your divs whith class .column have no close tag

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed above code with 3 row 4 column image gallery

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="CS1.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS2.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS3.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="CS4.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS5.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS6.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
      </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="CS7.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS8.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS9.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="CS10.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS11.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
        <img src="CS12.jpg" alt="Counter Strike: Global Offensive Screenshot">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

updated css

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
}
```